# Routes - Slimframework

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to make a simple API that will print `cars` for me. So far I made a 3 simple routes:

```
$app('/api/cars', function($req, $res, $arg) {
    //Display all cars
});
$app('/api/cars/{brand}', function($req, $res, $arg) {
    //Display all cars based on brand
});
$app('/api/cars/{brand}/{model}', function($req, $res, $arg) {
    //Display all cars based on brand
});
```

And it works just fine. But what if I want to display cars with "?" `color?` let's say:
`api/cars/red` I am unable to.

I can't really do that, because it's looking for a brand name instead of a color.

Comment: You should create your api to accept a url query string e.g. `/api/cars?brand=audi&color=blue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the additional filters as GET parameters on the URL:

```
/api/cars?color=red

/api/cars/honda?color=red

/api/cars/honda/civic?color=red
```

Then you can use `$request->getParam('color')` to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your route you wouldn't be able to, because as you've pointed out it's looking for a brand. If you want a quick and dirty solution you could update your endpoints to be slightly more descriptive.

For example:

```
$app('/api/cars/brand/{brand}', function($req, $res, $arg) {
    //Display all cars based on brand
});
$app('/api/cars/color/{color}', function($req, $res, $arg) {
    //Display all cars based on color
});
```

This reduces any ambiguity on what the endpoint should expect. Ideally your API should accept query strings instead.